# xcode "expected unqualified-id" on cout

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to make a program to calculate the y component of a user-input number for 7 different aspect ratios. This is probably a simple problem somewhere in the declarations at the top, but I have very little experience with c++. I am writing in xcode. Thanks!

I'm getting the following error messages:

19:13: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_istream' and '')

32:6: Expected unqualified-id

```
    //
    //  aspect1.cpp
    //  aspectRatioCalculator
    //


    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number to calculate its complements at multiple aspect ratios." << endl;

    cin>> a >> endl;

    int b = (a*9)/17;
    int c = (a*9)/16;
    int d = (a*5)/8;
    int e = (a*4)/5;
    int f = (a*3)/5;
    int g = (a*3)/4;
    int h = (a*2)/3;

    cout << "17:9 | " << a << ":" << b << endl;
    cout << "16:9 | " << a << ":" << c << endl;
    cout << " 8:5 | " << a << ":" << d << endl;
    cout << " 5:4 | " << a << ":" << e << endl;
    cout << " 5:3 | " << a << ":" << f << endl;
    cout << " 4:3 | " << a << ":" << g << endl;
    cout << " 3:2 | " << a << ":" << h << endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::endl` is an output manipulator. It isn't meant to be used with input streams (which are used for *input*). Change this: `cin >> a >> endl;` to `cin >> a; cout << endl;`.